# JAVA Querydsl 4.1.4 complex query, setPath any with multiple filters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl, predicate

I'm using a JPA HIBERNATE H2 database for my project.

Currently I'm trying to build a predicate with partial predicates that are optional, everything worked fine until I had to create some complex queries.

I would like to filter my products to those that have a composition component whose default quantity is less than its maximum quantity

I wrote a function like this:

```
private BooleanExpression getBooleanPredicateComposition(ListPath<Product.Composition.Component, QProduct_Composition_Component> component, QProduct_Composition_Component qpath, Boolean params) {
        if(null == params) {
            return null;
        }
        BooleanExpression be = qpath.defaultQuantity.lt(qpath.maxQuantity);
        return (params ? be : component.size().gt(0).not());
    }
```

As a result of this the following sql is executed:

```
select
                    1 
                from
                    product$composition product_co3_ 
                inner join
                    product$composition_component component4_ 
                        on product_co3_.composition_id=component4_.product$composition_composition_id

                inner join
                    product$composition_component component5_ 
                        on product_co3_.composition_id=component5_.product$composition_composition_id

                where
                    product_co3_.composition_id=product0_.composition_composition_id 
                    and product_co3_.composition_id=product0_.composition_composition_id 
                    and component4_.default_quantity<component5_.max_quantity
```

But I want an sql where the component4_default_quantity is in relation with its own max_quantity not with another joined table like I have currently.

Im not an sql expert for sure, actually I have very little experience with it but I think it should be something like this:

```
select
                    1 
                from
                    product$composition product_co3_ 
                inner join
                    product$composition_component component4_ 
                        on product_co3_.composition_id=component4_.product$composition_composition_id 
                where
                    product_co3_.composition_id=product0_.composition_composition_id 
                    and product_co3_.composition_id=product0_.composition_composition_id 
                    and component4_.default_quantity<component4_.max_quantity
```

So how should I code it?

I tried many different techniques like building up a new JPAExpression or Referring to the base class which is QProduct_Composition_Component.component, but none of them seems to be working for me..

Thank you in advance!

## Update:

The rest of the code from where I call this function

```
 public Predicate getPredicate(ComplexProduct complexProduct) {
        return new BooleanBuilder()
                .and(PRODUCT.country.eq(complexProduct.getCountry()))
                .and(PRODUCT.storeId.eq(complexProduct.getStore()))
                .and(getPartialPredicate(complexProduct).build());
    }

    private WhereClauseBuilder getPartialPredicate(ComplexProduct complexProduct) {
        WhereClauseBuilder whereClauseBuilder = new WhereClauseBuilder()
                .optionalAnd(PRODUCT.onOutage::eq,complexProduct.getOnOutage())
                .optionalAnd(getBooleanPredicateZeroPriced(PRODUCT.priceList.priceTag.pricing.any().price,complexProduct.getZeroPriced(), complexProduct.getNullPriceAllowed()))
                .optionalAnd(getBooleanPredicateSalable(PRODUCT.salable, complexProduct.getSalable()))
                .optionalAnd(getBooleanPredicateIsActive(PRODUCT.isActive, complexProduct.getIsActive()))
                .optionalAnd(getBooleanPredicateHasPromotionTimeRestriction(PRODUCT.promotion.timeRestrictions, complexProduct.getHasPromotionTimeRestriction()))
                .optionalAnd(getBooleanPredicateString(PRODUCT.grillGroup, complexProduct.getGrillGroup()))
                .optionalAnd(getBooleanPredicateExistsAndHasElement(PRODUCT.canAdds.component, complexProduct.getGrilledCanAdd()))
                .optionalAnd(getBooleanPredicateExistsAndHasElement(PRODUCT.comments.component, complexProduct.getGrilledComment()))
                .optionalAnd(getBooleanPredicateExistsAndHasElement(PRODUCT.choices.component, complexProduct.getGrilledChoice()))
                .optionalAnd(getBooleanPredicateComposition(PRODUCT.composition.component, PRODUCT.composition.component.any(), complexProduct.getCompositionNeeded()))
                .optionalAnd(getBooleanPredicateAvailability(PRODUCT, complexProduct.getTime(), complexProduct.getTime(), complexProduct.getDayName(), complexProduct.getAvailableAt()))
                .optionalAnd(getBooleanPredicateCustomParameter(PRODUCT.customParameters, "nutritionalInfoEnergy",complexProduct.getNutritionalInfoEnergy()));
        if(complexProduct.getDistributions() != null) {
            addDistributionFilters(whereClauseBuilder, complexProduct.getDistributions().stream().map(distribution -> distribution.name()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
        WhereClauseBuilder partialWhere = null;
        if(complexProduct.getType() != null) {
            if(complexProduct.getType() != null) {
                if (partialWhere == null) {
                    partialWhere = new WhereClauseBuilder();
                }
                partialWhere = partialWhere.optionalOr(PRODUCT.productClass::eq,  complexProduct.getType().getName());
            }
        }
        if(partialWhere != null) {
            whereClauseBuilder.optionalAnd(partialWhere.build());
        }

        return whereClauseBuilder;
    }
```

Comment: please post the rest of your code? what have you got calling this method?

Comment: I have updated the post, @MichaelWiles is it enough?